# Finding IDs based on one unique Output Value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

I have two columns in a dataframe  **advertisementID** and **Payout**, Many **advertisementID's** have more than one **Payout** value, but I need to find those **advertisementID's** which have only *one* unique **Payout** value. How to do it in R ?

Example:

```
advertisementID   Payout  
      1              10  
      2              3  
      1              10  
      2              4 
      3              5
      3              4
```

So the output should be like this:

```
advertisementID   Payout  
       1            10
```

as advertisementID 1 is having payout value unique which is 10

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output.  Also, the question is not clear

Comment: See [how to make a great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @akrun I have edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using R base:

```
new <- aggregate(Payout ~ advertisementID, dt, unique) 
new[lengths(new$Payout)==1, ]
```

output:

```
  advertisementID Payout
1               1     10
```

Or in a cleaner way with `magrittr`:

```
library(magrittr)
aggregate(Payout ~ advertisementID, dt, unique) %>% subset(lengths(Payout)==1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  group_by(advertisementID) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(Payout) == 1) %>%
  distinct(advertisementID, Payout) %>%
  ungroup()
dt2
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  advertisementID Payout
            <int>  <int>
1               1     10
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "advertisementID   Payout  
      1              10  
                 2              3  
                 1              10  
                 2              4 
                 3              5
                 3              4",
                 header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.